# How do I search for an element in a JS object (building a Discord Bot - discord.js)

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

Essentially I need to check whether or not an input is in one object, if not, then check another object.

I have a CSV file with data, which has names of countries in full as the first column of each row.

An example is:

United Kingdom,4,8,1,0

The bot gets the data from **c.(countryname or countrycode)** e.g. c.uk *or* c.unitedkingdom would be United Kingdom in the csv file.

I've added lots of comments to hopefully make it easier to read!

```js
else if((msg.content.split('.')[1] != null)){
        let arr1 = {
            "AD":"Andorra",
            "AE":"U A E",
        }
        let arr11 = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arr1).map(e=>e.reverse())); //reversed original object to allow for full country names to be inputted
        let arr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr11).replace(/"\s+|\s+"/g,'"')); //strips of blank spaces to match input
        var country = msg.content.split('.')[1]; //splits c.uk to ['c.','uk']
        if(arr1[country]){ // checking if user inputted a string that is a country code
            //EXECUTE on found in first array. e.g. user entered 'ad', and the program finds 'Andorra'
            msg.channel.send('you entered **' + country + '** and the checking was **' + arr1[country] + '** [Using arr1]');
        }
        else if(arr2[country]){ //checking if user inputted country name
            //EXECUTE on found unitedkingdom to UK - add .tolowerCase
            msg.channel.send('you entered **' + country + '** and the checking was **' + arr2[country] + '** [Using arr2]');
        } else {
            msg.channel.send('else statement executed');
        }


    }
```

At the moment, this always prints ('else statement executed').

Any help would be appreciated - thank you!

Comment: You need to capitalize the country value first before the if statements. The reason it is going into the else is because it is not able to find a 'ad' in the object. You can also check if the key is present in a map or not by using the map.keys() method which returns an array of the keys from you map. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tries check for `arr1[country]`, where `country` can be in different case, like `arr1['uk']`, when `UK`-key in your object in upper case.

Make something like this:

```
let arr1 = {
  "AD":"Andorra",
  "AE":"U A E",
}

// remove spaces from value, make it upper case and reverse
const makeObj = ([key, value]) => {
  // array [VALUE, key]
  let result = [value.toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, ''), key];
  return result;
}

let arr2 = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arr1).map(makeObj)); // reverse object
arr1 = Object.assign(arr1, arr2); // make single object
let country = msg.content.split('.')[1].toUpperCase(); // requested country in upper case

if(arr1[country]){
  msg.channel.send(country, arr1[country]);
} else {
  msg.channel.send('else statement executed');
}
```